# NHibernate 2nd Level cache between sessions

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

So from what i understand, the 2nd level cache should persist between Sessions as its stored on **SessionFactory** level, I am however not able to produce this result.

I'm not sure where the problem lies but my session factory configuration is as follows:

```
var hibernateConfig = Fluently.Configure();
hibernateConfig.Database(MySQLConfiguration
              .Standard
              .ConnectionString(cs => cs.Server(sqlConfig["host"].ToString())
                .Database(sqlConfig["database"].ToString())
                .Username(sqlConfig["username"].ToString())
                .Password(sqlConfig["password"].ToString())
              ));
hibernateConfig.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromNamespaceOf<NodeEntity>());
hibernateConfig.Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache().UseSecondLevelCache().ProviderClass<NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider>());
SessionFactory = hibernateConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
```

The session factory is then served through an Singleton.

In My App.config i have defined Cache Region as follows:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="syscache" type="NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheSectionHandler, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<syscache>
    <cache region="Entities" expiration="3600" priority="5" />
    <cache region="ShortTerm" expiration="900" priority="3" />
</syscache>
```

Which implies that the cache (I'm using Entities Region) should persist in 60 minutes.

The application uses Repository pattern for handling entities, I was suspecting that something was wrong here, but it seems not.

My test is done like this:

```
var factory = EntityManager.GetSessionFactory();
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    nodes = session.Query<NodeEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    cables = session.Query<CableEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - startTime);

    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    nodes = session.Query<NodeEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    cables = session.Query<CableEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - startTime);
}

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    nodes = session.Query<NodeEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    cables = session.Query<CableEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - startTime);

    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    nodes = session.Query<NodeEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    cables = session.Query<CableEntity>().Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - startTime);
}
```

This code gives me following results from prints:

```
00:00:12.0721413
00:00:00.0350096
00:00:10.6184812
00:00:00.0350119
```

From what i read from this is that the cache works fine in the **same** session, but does not when opening a new session

All my Entities also have following code in its mapping:

```
Cache.ReadWrite().Region("Entities");
```

What am i missing here? Is it possible at all to maintain cache between sessions?
At this example im using HashTableProvider. Ive also tried with Syscache without any luck.

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but you can specify a cache region on the query itself as well. I've always assigned a region for my queries. To answer the main question: _Is it possible at all to maintain cache between sessions?_ the answer is *Yes, I do it all the time.*, but I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to be working for you in this case.

Comment: I tried to add CacheRegion definition in the query. Did not work :(... My Entities does reference other Entities. Is this something that may affect caching?